# How can I have a page on a site that isn't a 'Page' in the WordPress sense?

Tags: theme-development, routing

I have created a system whereby users can sign up and then be searched for on the frontend.  The search uses `WP_User_Query` and works great.

I want each user to have their own profile page, which shows all sorts of info tied to their account.  All of the data is there, but I'm unsure how or where I can build these profile pages.

The URLs of these pages will be /member/[slug]/[ID]
EG: /member/mike/32

I'd like a theme file that is called when this route is hit.  I've thought about having a rewrite rule within .htaccess and a flat .php file that calls `wp-load.php`, and then attempts to load the header and footer.  That seems to be extremely nonsensical to me though.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new endpoint for your profile page. There's no need to manage anything with the htaccess. WordPress will do it for you.

[codex: add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Another way (half solution) is to create a template file and load it via `template_include` hook. But it will not get the user name (as it is).

```
add_filter( 'template_include',  array($this, 'profile_page'), 99 );

function profile_page($templates){
    if ( is_page( 'profile-page' ) ) {
        $new_template = YOURPLUGIN_DIR .'templates/profile-page';
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a page with permalink set to profile-page and create functions and profile page content...

EDIT:

Here a rewrite complete class for a profile user page, without the need to create a page.

```
class wpse242114{

public function __construct(){

    add_action( 'wp_loaded', array($this,'_flush_rules') );
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', array($this,'_insert_rewrite_rules') );
    add_filter( 'query_vars', array($this,'_insert_query_vars') );
    add_filter( 'template_include',  array($this, '_get_plugin_template'), 99 );
}

public function _flush_rules() {
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(profile)/(\d*)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

public function _insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
$newrules = array();
$newrules['(profile)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]';
return $newrules + $rules;
}

public function _insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
array_push( $vars, 'id' );
return $vars;
}

public function _get_plugin_template($template){
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->query['name'] == 'profile') {

        $new_template = APIKEYABLE_DIR .'includes/templates/page-login.php';
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
  }
}
```

The template file example:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
   <div id="main-grid" class="row">

      <div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-8">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        $userid = get_current_user_id();

        $user = new WP_User($userid);

        if ( $user->exists() ) {
            // do something

        }

       </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div><!-- .row -->
```

Comment: That link is empty. How does it know what template to load, and how can I define the route? Thanks

Comment: @mikemike the link has been fixed

Comment: Hmmm, I think it's close but I'm not sure how I can achieve what I need with that. I was sort of hoping for a function that allows a route to be defined that points to a file in the theme, like:  add_rewrite_page('member/(:s)/(:n)', 'memberprofile.php');

Comment: @mikemike : I edit my answer

Comment: Thanks @Benoti but I can't get this working.  I created a file called `wpse242114.php`, included it into my functions.php then called `new wpse2421124();`.  If I add a `die()` into `__construct();` that works so the file is being called and processed.  If I visit `/profile`, `/profile/123` or `/profile/test/123` I just get a 404 as though the rewrite rule hasn't been defined.  No errors.  Any idea?

Comment: Yes, it's a dirty solution for an old plugin i've done... I never try to make it run in the theme function. Are you sure about the template file location ? If i run it on a fresh install, it gives me a page not found title but i can retrieve the asked content.